# Toggle form inside v-for using vue.js

Tags: vue.js, v-for

How can i toggle form inside v-for loop,I have a form inside v-for which i want to display (toggle) on click.
But when i click all the form inside the v-for gets toggled.

Secondly is it better approach to keep the form inside the loop,when have large amount of data inside loop or load it as a separate component.

This is what i am trying to do.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [{
        text: "Learn JavaScript"
      },
      {
        text: "Learn Vue"
      },
      {
        text: "Play around in JSFiddle"
      },
      {
        text: "Build something awesome"
      }
    ],
    show: ''
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo) {
      this.show = !this.show
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="(todo,key) in todos">
      <p>
        {{ key+1 }} - {{ todo.text}} <span @click="toggle(todo)"><b>Contact</b></span>
        <div v-if="show">
          <hr />
          <p>
            <label>Message</label>
            <input type="text">
          </p>
          <hr />
        </div>
      </p>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is only 1 reactive variable `show`. Setting it to true while all form is using `v-if="show"`, will show everything.

You can set `show` to something that each form uniquely have. For example, its text, and perform a `v-if` using its text.

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/umaszo9c/

change `v-if="show"` to `v-if="show === todo.text"`

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="(todo,key) in todos">
      <p>
        {{ key+1 }} - {{ todo.text}} <span @click="toggle(todo)"><b>Contact</b></span>
        <div v-if="show === todo.text">
          <hr />
          <p>
            <label>Message</label>
            <input type="text">
          </p>
          <hr />
        </div>
      </p>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

change `toggle` method

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [{
        text: "Learn JavaScript"
      },
      {
        text: "Learn Vue"
      },
      {
        text: "Play around in JSFiddle"
      },
      {
        text: "Build something awesome"
      }
    ],
    show: ''
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo) {
      if (this.show === todo.text)
        this.show = false
      else
        this.show = todo.text
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much,this is what i was looking for.
Can you please answer it is better approach to load form like this inside v-for ? or create and load new component ?

Comment: @KhiradBanu Personally, if the form is as simple as the example, I would not separate it into components. But if it gets any more complex, I would. There is no right or wrong way, it just depends on how you wanna structure your code.

Comment: Suppose we have a list of 1000 to dos,then iterating form like this will not impact performance ?

Comment: @KhiradBanu Even if it's a component, it also will have to loop 1000 times to render 1000 components, isn't it ?

Comment: @KhiradBanu When in doubt, just use component.

Comment: No,what i mean to just call a component when clicked,not placing it inside the v-for

Comment: @KhiradBanu I don't understand what do you mean by `call a component when clicked`. That doesn't sound like Vue. Might need an example to understand what you mean. or try asking @jacky? his solution works well too

Answer (score 1):

property "show" should be a prop of todo,not prop of data

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [{
        text: "Learn JavaScript"
      },
      {
        text: "Learn Vue"
      },
      {
        text: "Play around in JSFiddle"
      },
      {
        text: "Build something awesome"
      }
    ].map(o=>({...o,show:false}))
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo) {
      todo.show = !todo.show
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="(todo,key) in todos">
      <p>
        {{ key+1 }} - {{ todo.text}} <span @click="toggle(todo)"><b>Contact</b></span>
        <div v-if="todo.show">
          <hr />
          <p>
            <label>Message</label>
            <input type="text">
          </p>
          <hr />
        </div>
      </p>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please guide me is it a good approach to keep this form inside a loop, Or create new component and on click event load that component instead?

Comment: This depends on the complexity and performance overhead of loading the content in your loop.